# Find the area of the enclosed region

Tags: calculus

The region is enclosed by the curves $y=\sqrt{x+2}$, $y=\frac1{x+1}$, and lies between $x=0$ and $x=2$. Help please, any work would be helpful. Thank you!

Comment: Any work (of your own) would be helpful in understanding what you are stuck on. Have you drawn the region?

Comment: Dang, I submitted my edit just after Sujaan's....

Answer (score 0):

**Hint.** Since, for $x$ such that $0\leq x\leq2$, we have $\displaystyle \sqrt{x+2} > \frac1{x+1}$, then the desired area $A$ is such that
$$
A =\int_0^2 \sqrt{x+2} \:dx-\int_0^2 \frac1{x+1} \:dx
$$
The second integral on the right hand side is easy to find out, for the first integral just write $\displaystyle \sqrt{x+2}=(x+2)^{1/2}$.